# Solr 9 not loading but installed correctly, config set generate issue - Drupal

Tags: java, solr, drupal

I have installed solr 9.0.0 on Apache2 Ubuntu 18.04 vagrant box. after the solr installation on my drupal site the solr page looks as below:

[image]

But when trying to open the solr url on browser - http://192.168.33.93:8983/solr/#/solr_core I see the below error:

[image]

Also tried http://localhost:8983/solr/#/solr_core produces the same error. Further, upon clicking the "Get condig.zip" button I see this error -    `Drupal\search_api_solr\SearchApiSolrException: No config-set template found for Solr branch 9.x in Drupal\search_api_solr\Controller\SolrConfigSetController->getConfigFiles() (line 285 of /vagrant/web/modules/contrib/search_api_solr/src/Controller/SolrConfigSetController.php)`.

Any help on how the issue can be resolved?

Comment: It seems your firewall is refusing "public" connections (coming from the outside) on port 8983, which is normal by default. In this situation you can either allow them (eg. using firewalld `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8983/tcp`), or use a proxy (eg. mapping `/solr` on http port to `http://localhost:8983/solr`).

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced a similar issue with Solr 9 service started but no webpage, seems by default it binds to IPV6.  Disable ipv6 and edit the below adding the actual ip address.

"Solr now binds to localhost network interface by default for better out of the box security. Administrators that need Solr exposed more broadly can change the SOLR_JETTY_HOST property in their Solr include (solr.in.sh/solr.in.cmd) file."

if you installed as a service edit: /etc/default/solr.in.sh

standalone: solr-9.0.0/bin/solr.in.sh

Comment: set it to: SOLR_JETTY_HOST="0.0.0.0" if you want to open it more widely and don't have the specific IP to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to figure out the problem. I was trying to install Solr 9 on Drupal 9.x which is not a possible thing. Drupal 9.x supported until solr 8. There was a config mismatch due to that. So I had to role back to solr 8 and re-upload correct configs, re-index my contents and everything worked correctly.